# JS Change Element's Color Onclick Undefined color

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, colors

I want to make a color changer button but after the last click, the color will be set undefined. Any idea how to remove it?

```js
var color = ["Orange", "Red", "Green", "Blue"];
            var i = 0;
            document.querySelector(".changeColorBtn").addEventListener("click", 
                function() {
                i = i < color.length ? ++i : 0;
                $('*[id="changeColor"]').css('color', color[i]);
                $('*[id="changeColorBack"]').css('background', color[i]);
                document.querySelector('.changeColr').innerHTML = color[i];
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="changeColr" id="changeColor">COLOR</h1>

<button class="changeColorBtn">Change</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indexes start counting from 0, while `.length` starts counting from 1.

So, this line:

```
i = i < color.length ? ++i : 0;
```

Needs to be:

```
i = i < color.length-1 ? ++i : 0;
```

Because without subtracting 1 from the `.length` you attempt to access an array index that is one higher than exists.

```js
var color = ["Orange", "Red", "Green", "Blue"];
            var i = 0;
            document.querySelector(".changeColorBtn").addEventListener("click", 
                function() {
                i = i < color.length-1 ? ++i : 0;
                $('*[id="changeColor"]').css('color', color[i]);
                $('*[id="changeColorBack"]').css('background', color[i]);
                document.querySelector('.changeColr').innerHTML = color[i];
            })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="changeColr" id="changeColor">COLOR</h1>

<button class="changeColorBtn">Change</button>
```